# Using values from an array for a boxplot

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, boxplot

I'm working on a practice problem for Python which requires that I find the min, max and median of an array and than use these values in construction of a box plot. I'm using the array "valid_opening_duration_list" and wanting to convert that into a form that I can use for my boxplot but I'm having some issues.

```
import statistics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Maximum Opening Duration is", max(valid_opening_duration_list))
print("Minimun Opening Duration is", min(valid_opening_duration_list))
print('The Median Opening Duration is', statistics.median(valid_opening_duration_list))

scores = valid_opening_duration_list(loc=5, size=100)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax.boxplot(scores, 0, labels=['Prac test'])
ax.set_ylabel('Scores', fontsize=16)
ax.set_title('Score BoxPlot', fontsize=16)
```

The program is telling me that its unable to call the object. Is there any way I can fix this?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-198-a2257e98b110> in <module>()
     11 print('The Median Opening Duration is', statistics.median(valid_opening_duration_list))
     12 
---> 13 scores = valid_opening_duration_list(loc=5, size=100)
     14 
     15 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because you are trying to call your numpy array as a function.

Since you are trying to copy the contents of valid_opening_duration_list to scores. You want to use the numpy.copy function.

change line 13 to

```
scores = np.copy(valid_opening_duration_list)
```

this will copy the contents of valid_opening_duration_list to scores.

Comment: Sorry, I only started coding a few weeks ago and I'm mostly winging it but how in this case would I not call it as a function?

Comment: could you tell me what exactly do you want scores to contain? I can write the correct code for you

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to get scores to contain an array of datetime values, which is what "valid_opening_duration_list" contains.